# how to add text prefix to sqlite query?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio

I am using this query to retrieve 4 values from a table:-

```
select * from table1;
```

For which i am getting an output:-

```
1

2

3

4
```

But i want it to look like :-

```
a=1

b=2

c=3

d=4
```

How to do it?

Comment: This character data should either be in a table already, or you should introduce it from you calling code.

Comment: how do i add it in my code?

Comment: Well I don't know your code, because you never showed us any.  I have the general feeling that your character data should be in a SQL table somewhere.

Comment: I'll have to add extra text in query,right?

Comment: Here's the deal: SQL is good for storing data and then extracting what you stored.  It is not good at generating data in a query.  Also, the letters you want are not available in any function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your column is called **id** and if values are only between 1 and 26 then the following will work :-

```
SELECT char(id + 96)||'='||id AS myrow  FROM table1;
```

e.g.:-

**table1** is :-

[image]

**Result** is :-

[image]

- myrow could be changed to suit

You could use

```
SELECT char((((id-1) % 26)+1)+ 96)||'='||id AS myrow  FROM table1;
```

Which would then use only letters a-z for any integer number.

e.g. if **table1** were :-

[image]

The **Result** would be :-

[image]